# dc.js - re-arrange labels in row chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I've plotted a row chart using `dc.js`.

Labels in that are 7 days of a week. But the order of the labels are in ascending order starting from Friday to Wednesday.

But i wanted to make it from Monday to Sunday.

Someone please help me in re-ordering those labels in `rowChart`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the ordering function: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#orderingorderfunction

You'll need to pass it a javascript function that translates the labels to a properly sorted number.

For example:

```
.ordering(function(d) {
    if(d.value == "Monday") return 0;
    else if(d.value == "Tuesday") return 1;
    // handle all days 
});
```

Comment: Be aware that `.ordering(..)` will work on the chart itself, as in `myRowChart.ordering(...)`, and not in a group as in `myRowChart.dimension(..).group(..).ordering(...)`